# Checking multiple strings for a specific number

Tags: php, function, count

Here is some part of my code:

```
<?php
                $terning1 = rand(1,6);
                $terning2 = rand(1,6);
                $terning3 = rand(1,6);
                $terning4 = rand(1,6);
                $terning5 = rand(1,6);
                $terning6 = rand(1,6);
//Here I need a system to check how many of them that gets number 6
?>
```

What I need is way to check how many of $terning1-6 that returns the number 6. Let's say $terning1 and $terning4 is then I need a way to tell me that 2 of them are 6. I don't know how I can do this as I've never done something like that before.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way you've named your variables, you can use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to loop through them:

```
$sixes = 0;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
    $variable = "terning$i";
    if ($$variable === 6) {
        $sixes++;
    }
}
```

But I would stongly recommend using an array instead to store your numbers, and count the sixes as you go:

```
$terning = array();
$sixes = 0;
for($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++){
    $terning[$i] = rand(1, 6);
    if ($terning[$i] === 6)
    {
        $sixes++;
    }
}
```

Or to count them afterwards:

`$sixes = count(array_keys($terning, 6));`

Answer (score 0):

if you can store everything in an array `$terning`

then,

```
if (in_array(6,$terning )) {
    //Do Something
}
```

Comment: Sorry but i dont know how to store all those in a array, and inn this code how do i get how many of em that were 6? like $howmany = SOMETHING; //Should give me the amount of em that were 6

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [array_count_values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) function on an array of terning values like this:

```
    // Variable to determine the amount of randomly generated numbers
    $amountOfTernings = 6;

    $terningsArray = [];

    // Storing the random numbers in an array
    for($i = 0; $i < $amountOfTernings; $i++) {
        $terningsArray[] = rand(1, 6);
    }

    // Constructs an array that counts the number of times a number has occurred
    $terningOccurrences = array_count_values($terningsArray);

    // Variable that stores the number of occurrences of 6
    $howManySixes = isset($terningOccurrences[6]) ? $terningOccurrences[6] : 0;
```

Comment: How can i use echo to tell the number?